# Configuring nginx with php5-fpm for joomla site

Tags: php, nginx, joomla

I'm trying to rise up web site on joomla3 with php5-fpm and nginx. It works, but only the main page. Other pages with .html extentions like this '/reports/april.html' aren't work, it returns 404 not found error. I guess something missed in my nginx config file, please give me a hint.

```
server{
    server_name acbr.loc;
     access_log /var/log/nginx/acbr.access.log;
     error_log  /var/log/nginx/acbr.error.log;

     root /home/oleshko/design/acbr;

     location ~ \.php$ {
         try_files $uri = 404;
         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     }

# порядок индексов    
     location /
     {
         index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

docs.joomla.org/Nginx
off cause )))